# Создание парсера Python

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть страница по монетизации сайта, пытаюсь сделать парсер.

На данной странице, когда водишь курсором по диаграмме, изменяется `position` в теге `div class: c3-tooltip-container`, в результате изменяется значение самого `value-container` по суммам и по датам.

Прописывая фрагмент кода ниже:

```
soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser') 
div=soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'value-container'})
print(div)
```

У меня не выдается в переменной `div` ничего, подскажите в чем ошибка и правильный ли вообще принцип парсинга данного сайта через библиотеку `requests` и `bs4`?

Comment: Добавьте ссылку на страницу, или код страницы в виде "кода". Вдруг, тот кто захочет вам помочь, решить проверить свои гипотезы.

Comment: Значение в `div.value-container` формируется javascript'ом, а ваш парсер его выполнять не умеет. Либо используйте Selenium, либо анализируйте структуру запросов со страницы и пытайтесь повторить их из своего парсера.

Comment: Александр, по поводу удаленного вопроса, что помогло в итоге?